# Calculate the time difference based on the hour between the present time and the time of the last update

Tags: python, django

I want to identify objects that have been updated for 24 hours.

my model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d/')
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

my view:

```
def home(request):
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    return render(request, 'shop_app/home.html', {'products': products})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you trying to get a result which values for the `updated` field is `CurrentDateTime - 24 hours` which is `1 day`.

which can be achieved by adding another parameter in the filter tag i.e `updated >= valid_dt` where `valid_dt` is valid date time (current datetime - 1 day) calculated using `timedelta`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def home(request):
    valid_dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)

    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True, updated__gte=valid_dt)
    return render(request, 'shop_app/home.html', {'products': products})
```

NOTE :  If you want to alter the time which is not in terms of day/month/year, you can use `relativedelta`